# setting a fade to turbo_stream

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, turbo

Rails UJS has a compactness about it. In a single line of a `js.erb` file, one calls the dom_id, a partial AND gives it some interaction (that confirms the change in the object with a minimalist approach).  Example with jQuery library invoked.

```
$("#header").html("<%= j render 'header', collection: @trecks %>").css({ opacity: 0 }).fadeTo('slow',1);
```

with the goal of removing UJS and the reliance on jQuery,
What is the most succinct way to implement an equivalent in vanilla JS of `.fadeTo('slow',1)` on the turbo stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue I normally pose myself: The convention of separation of concerns...

Why do something in JS when the presentation layer can do it?  CSS.
In fact, jQuery was invoking css; go direct!

One can simply define the tag with a class

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag dom_id(@treck), class: 'fade-text' do %>
<% end %>
```

with some simple CSS and get the same effect.

```
.fade-text {
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {opacity:0;}
  100% {opacity:1;}
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {opacity:0;}
  100% {opacity:1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {opacity:0;}
  100% {opacity:1;}
}

@-o-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {opacity:0;}
  100% {opacity:1;}
}

@-ms-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {opacity:0;}
  100% {opacity:1;}
}
```